# Google Cloud Storage API returns no files when prefix option is used

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I have the following code:

```
async function gcs_test() {
  // Create a client
  const storage = new gcs.Storage()

  const [buckets] = await storage.getBuckets()
  const bucket = buckets[0]
  console.log(`Using bucket ${bucket.name}`)
  const [files] = await bucket.getFiles({prefix: 'Users/', delimiter: '/', autoPaginate: false})
  console.log('FILES:', JSON.stringify(files))
}
```

and whenever I use the `delimiter` option, I get nothing back. If I don't pass `delimiter` I get all the files starting with "Users/", such as "Users/foo/project/1", "Users/bar/project/2" and so on.

I'm guessing the reason this returns nothing when `delimiter` is set is that there aren't any *files* as such in `/Users`, only "directories" (all the files are deeper down). So my question really is: how to list "directories" in a bucket, given a prefix (parent dir)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Cloud REST API returns data for objects that match the `prefix`. This means directories.

If you review the REST API, you will see that the returned data (response) contains `prefixes`. This is a list of prefix matches. Process this list item.

Google's definition:

> The list of prefixes of objects matching-but-not-listed up to and
>   including the requested delimiter.

Example code to show how to process this:

```
bucket.getFiles({prefix: 'Users/', delimiter: '/', autoPaginate: false}, function(err, files, nextQuery, apiResponse) {
    // process files[] here
    // process apiResponse.prefixes[] here (subdirectory names)
});
```

[Google Cloud Storage Object Response Object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list#response)

[Google Documentation on listing objects](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles)

Comment: How weird, you have to use apiResponse for this! Not a normal API. Oh well, thanks!

Comment: apiResponse is always null for me :(

Comment: You need to have autoPaginate set to `false` to have the apiResponse object.
https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/main/src/bucket.ts#L741

Comment: Not that the apiResponse is available as the third object in the array returned by the promise bucket.getFiles:

```
const [files, _, apiResponse] = bucket.getFiles({ autoPaginate: false })
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Storage does not have "directories".  It has file paths with delimiters that simulate a hierarchical structure that makes it easy to organize and reason about your objects.  You can think of each file path as the unique key in a big hash that maps to the object.

If there are no objects that contain a certain prefix, then that prefix effectively does not exist at all - there can be no object name which is just a "directory" that has no children in the path.

Please read the Cloud Storage definition of [Object names](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#object-names) for more details.